# Managing memory for a single string

Tags: c++, string

To take in a string (including spaces) and write it to a file, I use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream myFile("readme.txt");

    string a;
    getline(cin, a);
    myFile << a;

    myFile.close();
}
```

But should I be managing the memory assigned to the string, and if so what's the easiest way?

Comment: Your string runs out of scope when the main function ends, so the memory is managed by the compiler. By the way: main must return a value.

Comment: @Machtl: No, this is fine; there is an implicit `return 0` at the end, guaranteed by the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `std::string` manages its own memory.

Comment: While we're at it, `std::ofstream` manages the file stream, making the `close` call unnecessary.

Comment: std::string provides also interface to help string in this task

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to.  Unlike C (where strings are pointers to arrays that have to be managed), The std::string class is an object which manages its own memory.  The memory for a is released correctly when the variable a goes out of scope at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, `std::string` (a d every other STL container, for that matter) manages its own memory, and will be freed when it goes out of scope.  If you want more control over when it goes out of scope, you can do this:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream myFile("readme.txt");

    {
    string a;
    getline(cin, a);
    myFile << a;
    } // <-- string is freed here

    // do other things...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ string template class provided in  is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>` and it manages the memory dynamically. So you shouldn't. You have still options however to help this class in this task. String provides for this purpose appropriate interface, [for example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve)

```
void reserve( size_type new_cap = 0 );
```

> Informs a std::basic_string object of a planned change in size, so
>   that it can manage the storage allocation appropriately.